# Using retrofit to make a @Post but sending a xml body content in Kotlin?

Tags: retrofit2

I am very new at Kotlin. I am wondering if this is possible to do it in Kotlin.

I have a request that is basically a POST to an endpoint, it sends information as part of the body, something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE...">
    <some more tags...>
      <request>
        <clientAuth>
          <client>
            {client-id}
          </client>
        </cientAuth>
    ....
```

So I basically received some parameters (Like client-id) and I need to form this xml (as far as I am doing it at postman) and send the request.

Checking some libraries I noticed with retrofit is sort of possible, but I have no idea, is it really possible?

I know for "form url enconder" requests is simpler by using `@FormUrlEncoded` but not sure if there is one for xmls...

So far I got this:

an interface...

```
@POST("user-endpoint")
fun clientRequest(
    @Field("clientId") clientId: String
): Deferred<Response<Void>>
```

and I invoke clientRequest from other function.

Testing the logic works fine for endpoints without parameters, but I have no idea how to send that xml, is it even possible?

I find out I can use tickaroo to represent my body as an object and then use retrofit without problem.

Comment: You are looking for `@Body`.

Comment: yes, I was thinking about using tickaroo and create an object that represents the XML, not sure if is possible... or would work

Comment: Why it woundn't? You can try to implement it and post here your attempt if something goes wrong.